# How to decode characters in Google Google Chrome history file when it’s copied to TextPad?

Tags: google-chrome, xml

I am developing a Chrome extension to analyze user history and perform some tasks.

For that using this path `C:\Users\Sad\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` I open History file in a TextPad. But in TextPad some information are showed in symbols. Screenshot below.

Is there anyway that I can translate them into readable content?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m pretty sure what you are seeing is some kind of binary/hex DB code that Chrome uses to store that data. Meaning you trying to access it directly like this won’t work. Instead, you should probably be using the `chrome.history` API to interact with the contents of the history file. As explained in the Google Chrome API docs:

> Use the chrome.history API to interact with the browser's record of visited pages. You can add, remove, and query for URLs in the browser's history.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that this file is a `sqlite db`.
The easiest way to read it if you don't wont to use the browser is write a small python script. use pythons `sqlite3 module`

You'll find tutorials on google how to do this is python